# concatenate two columns into one in R

Tags: r

My data

```
conc_data=structure(list(kod_nar.id = c(1L, 3L, 2L), 
    x123_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    x124_2 = c(0, 0.123, 0.122), 
    x125_3 = 0:2, 
    x126_4 = c(0, 0.234, 0.99)),
   .Names = c("kod_nar.id", "x123_1", "x124_2", "x125_3", "x126_4"), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

There are 4 columns here, but every 2 columns need to be combined into one, with the name of the first column.
In other words, each pair of columns should be combined into one with concatenating the values of digits. As a result, we will have only 2 columns in the data frame.   Each column in data frame has a pair.The number of columns is even.the columns are in order the first pair, the second pair, and so on

I.E. Output

```
  kod_nar.id   x123_1   x125_3
1          1        0        0
2          3 0(0.123) 1(0.234)
3          2 0(0.122)  2(0.99)
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Or:

```
conc_data$x123_1 <- with(conc_data, ifelse(x124_2 == 0, "0", sprintf("%d(%.3f)", x123_1, x124_2)))
conc_data$x125_3 <- with(conc_data, ifelse(x126_4 == 0, "0", sprintf("%d(%.3f)", x125_3, x126_4)))
```

Answer (score 4):

An option would be to loop over the sets of columns, use `sprintf` to format the columns of interest and `cbind` with the first column

```
out <- cbind(conc_data[1], sapply(list(2:3, 4:5), 
          function(i) sprintf("%d(%f)", 
        round(conc_data[,i[1]], 2), conc_data[,i[2]])))
```

---

If the value for '0' needs to be zero

```
out <- cbind(conc_data[1], sapply(list(2:3, 4:5), function(i) {
   dat <- conc_data[i]
   i1 <- !rowSums(dat != 0)
   v1 <- do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = "%d(%.3f)", dat))
   v1[i1] <- 0
    v1
    }))
names(out)[-1] <- names(conc_data)[c(2, 4)]
out
#  kod_nar.id   x123_1   x125_3
#1          1        0        0
#2          3 0(0.123) 1(0.234)
#3          2 0(0.122) 2(0.990)
```

---

Or more compactly

```
data.frame(c(conc_data[1], Map(sprintf, conc_data[c(2, 4)], 
        conc_data[c(3, 5)], MoreArgs = list(fmt = "%d(%.3f)"))))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can split every two columns using `split.default` and use `sapply` to `paste` the two columns together in the format required. We add names to the output by selecting althernating column name.

```
output <- cbind(conc_data[1], sapply(split.default(conc_data[-1], 
           rep(seq_along(conc_data), each = 2)[1:(ncol(conc_data) - 1)]), 
   function(x) paste0(x[[1]], "(", x[[2]], ")")))

names(output)[-1] <- names(conc_data)[-1][c(TRUE, FALSE)]

output
#  kod_nar.id   x123_1   x125_3
#1          1     0(0)     0(0)
#2          3 0(0.123) 1(0.234)
#3          2 0(0.122)  2(0.99)
```

Or maybe a bit simpler to split using `gl`

```
output <- cbind(conc_data[1], sapply(split.default(conc_data[-1],
 gl((ncol(conc_data) - 1)/2, 2)), 
   function(x) paste0(x[[1]], "(", x[[2]], ")")))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you melt to long format you can do this with data.table group operations and then dcast back to wide

```
df_long <- 
  melt(conc_data, 1)[
      , .(variable = variable[1],
          value = sprintf('%.0f(%.3f)', value[1], value[2]))
      , by = .(kod_nar.id, id = (rowid(kod_nar.id) - 1) %/% 2)]

out <- dcast(df_long, kod_nar.id ~ variable)

out
#    kod_nar.id   x123_1   x125_3
# 1:          1 0(0.000) 0(0.000)
# 2:          2 0(0.122) 2(0.990)
# 3:          3 0(0.123) 1(0.234)
```

If it's important to have just `'0'` on those first rows you could add this additional step

```
out <- out[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(grepl('[1-9]', x), x, '0'))]

out
#    kod_nar.id   x123_1   x125_3
# 1:          1        0        0
# 2:          2 0(0.122) 2(0.990)
# 3:          3 0(0.123) 1(0.234)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

conc_data %>%
 mutate(x123_1 = ifelse(x123_1 == x124_2, 
                         x123_1,
                         paste0(x123_1, "(", x124_2, ")")
                        ),
        x125_3 = ifelse(x125_3 == x126_4,
                        x125_3,
                        paste0(x125_3, "(", x126_4, ")")
                        )) %>%
 select(x123_1, x125_3)


    x123_1   x125_3
1        0        0
2 0(0.123) 1(0.234)
3 0(0.122)  2(0.99)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this e.g. by using `sapply` and `paste`. I'm assuming to print only one number if the numbers are equal in both columns:

```
tt  <- seq(2,ncol(conc_data),2)
res  <- cbind(conc_data[1], sapply(tt, function(i) {
  ifelse(conc_data[,i] != conc_data[,i+1], paste0(conc_data[,i], "(", conc_data[,i+1],")") ,paste0(conc_data[,i]))
}
))
names(res)[-1]  <- names(conc_data)[s]
res
#  kod_nar.id   x123_1   x125_3
#1          1        0        0
#2          3 0(0.123) 1(0.234)
#3          2 0(0.122)  2(0.99)
```

Or by using the column name direct in `sapply`:

```
tt  <- seq(2,ncol(conc_data),2)
cbind(conc_data[1], sapply(names(conc_data)[tt], function(i) {
  i2  <- which(names(conc_data) == i)+1
  ifelse(conc_data[,i] != conc_data[,i2], paste0(conc_data[,i], "(", conc_data[,i2],")") ,paste0(conc_data[,i]))
  }
))
#  kod_nar.id   x123_1   x125_3
#1          1        0        0
#2          3 0(0.123) 1(0.234)
#3          2 0(0.122)  2(0.99)
```