# Paste multiple columns based on other columns names - R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to `paste` multiple columns together based on some columns names. I already looked on stack for pasting and joining columns together but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Sample data :

```
data <- data.frame(col1= c(10,20),
                   col2= c(4,8),
                   col1_pct= c(0.20, 0.30),
                   col2_pct= c(0.40, 0.87))

Output :

  col1 col2 col1_pct col2_pct
1   10    4      0.2     0.40
2   20    8      0.3     0.87
```

The output I want :

```
 col1_new col2_new
1   10 (0.2)   4 (0.40)
2   20 (0.3)   8 (0.87)
```

The real data contains a lot of columns so I can't simply `paste()` those manually. So I was wondering if there was a way to paste together all the columns where the `name` match `name_pct` just like in the output.

I already tried a few things with `lapply()` and some `loop` but didn't succeed. I know I have to somehow use the character string `_pct` and probably the `names` function but I'm not sure how to proceed for this. Could someone help me please?

Thank you.

Edit: the columns names are not known since they are part of a function.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57057504/10488504

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to use `sprintf` by looping through alternate columns

```
data.frame(setNames(lapply(list(c(1,3), c(2, 4)), function(i) 
     do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = "%d (%0.2f)",
        data[i]))), paste0(names(data)[1:2], "_new")))
#   col1_new col2_new
#1 10 (0.20) 4 (0.40)
#2 20 (0.30) 8 (0.87)
```

---

It can be converted to tidyverse as well

```
library(tidyverse0
map2_df(data %>% 
           select(1:2), 
        data %>% 
           select(matches("pct")), ~  sprintf("%d (%0.2f)", .x, .y)) %>%
   rename_all(~ str_c(., "_new"))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# col1_new  col2_new
#  <chr>     <chr>   
#1 10 (0.20) 4 (0.40)
#2 20 (0.30) 8 (0.87)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun!

Comment: Quick question, what if I have 100 of those columns? Is there way to paste them without having to do ``c(1,3)``, ``c(2.4)``, etc. ?

Comment: @Gainz. i would select based on the pattern with `grep` ie. `i1 <- grepl('pct', names(data)); lapply(list(!i1, i1), function(x)`

Comment: Thanks that is what I was really looking for, I should have make my question clearer! Thank you, I am gonna accept the answer when stack will allow me too.

Comment: @Gainz If we use the `i1`, !i1 it would be `Map(function(x, y) sprintf("%d %0.2f", x, y), data[!i1], data[i1])`